# Spark Scala - How to explode a column into multiple rows in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this

```
+----------+-------------+
|A         |Devices      |
+----------+-------+------
|house1    |[100,101,102]|
|house1    |[103,104]    |
+----------+-------------+
```

And I want to explode the column 'Devices' into multiple rows. My final dataframe should look like this

```
+----------+--------+
|A         |Devices |
+----------+--------+
|house1    |100     |
|house1    |101     |
|house1    |102     |
|house1    |103     |
|house1    |104     |
+----------+--------+
```

The schema of the table is

```
 root 
  |-- A: String (nullable = true)
  |-- Devices: array (nullable = true)
  |   |-- element: String (containsNull = true)
```

I tried doing this but it is showing error (UnresolvedAttribute in $"Devices")

> `Df.withColumn("c", explode(split($"Devices","\\,")))`

Comment: You shouldn't need the split function. Your strings dont have commas

Comment: Yes, Thanks @OneCricketeer! I updated the question

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. I am able to find the answer using explode(columnName)

Answer (score 2):

```
Df.select(col("A"),explode(col("devices"))
```

Using this I am able to find the required answer

Comment: The `$`  should work, but you need to `import spark.implicits._`